# javascript object's function undefined in Vue's mounted hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a js file that I call to my another js file.

The first js file looks like this:

**app.js**

```
const app = {
    ...functions
    ,
    plugins: {
        createTab: function(options) { ... }
    }

}
```

Now, I call the app.js inside another js called **global.tab.js** like this...

```
import { app } from '.app.js';
export const initTab = () => {
    app.plugins.createTab(some_parameters);
}
```

now in my vue component,
I called the **global.tab.js** like this..

```
import { initTab } from './js/global.tab.js';
export default {
    ...
    ...
    mounted() {
        initTab();
    }
}
```

but when I run the project, I get error saying : `[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined"`

Comment: Did you export the `app` object from *app.js*?  It's not shown.

Comment: It's probably best to delete the question if that was the only issue